# What templating library can be used with Asp .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 5 app I need to be able to dynamically construct a list of fully qualified external  URL hyperlinks, alone with some additional data, which will come from the Model passed in. I figure - I will need to construct my anchor tags something like this:

```
<a href="{{fullUrlName}}" class="list-group-item" target="_blank">{{linkDisplayName}}</a>
```

with AngularJS this would be natural, but, I have no idea how this is done in MVC.

Is there a templating library that can be used for this?

Comment: Well, you can do this with Razor? Just pass a list of links to the View, use a loop and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a model to Hold the Links

```
public class LinkObject
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

2) In your `Action` you can use `ViewBag`, `ViewData` or even pass the list inside you `Model`. I will show you how to do using ViewBag

```
public ActionResult MyDynamicView()
{
    //Other stuff and code here

    ViewBag.LinkList = new List<LinkObject>()
    {
        new LinkObject{ Link ="http://mylink1.com", Description = "Link 1"},
        new LinkObject{ Link ="http://mylink2.com", Description = "Link 2"},
        new LinkObject{ Link ="http://mylink3.com", Description = "Link 3"}
    };

    return View(/*pass the model if you have one*/);
}
```

3) In the View, just use a loop:

```
@foreach (var item in (List<LinkObject>)ViewBag.LinkList)
{
    <a href="@item.Link" class="list-group-item" target="_blank">@item.Description</a> 
}
```

Comment: You should avoid having the server construct too much html because it will waste bandwidth and increase the amount of time it takes a page to load.

Comment: The server ALWAYS constructs HTML, your comment makes literally no sense.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Doing it in a loop is a waste of resource. Why should the server send extra text, specifically `<a href="" class="list-group-item" target="_blank"></a>`, for every single link? I hope you consider optimizing the way you construct html in razor.

Comment: You have to return the View anyway, just do the job in the server. The View engine will process the View anyway to return to the client. Doing another http call to the server to return something that should be done in the first moment is not a good pratice. Another thread to process a JSON request? Why? Its a link!

Comment: @Fals - It is a set of links, and for each link you are sending an extra 55 characters for no reason.

Comment: Actually it would be much much much much less that 55 characters, maybe 17 probably less.  I don't know anyone who turns off gzip http compression.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - `<a href="" class="list-group-item" target="_blank"></a>` is how many characters? All of this is extra html with no need to be passed from the server.

Comment: I guess you don't know what [Http Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) is?  It's been around for more than 10 years. Or do you not know what [Data Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) is?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - You edited your comment at the end of the window to include the remark about compression. It is unfortunately common for people to not support some sort of compression, especially with `.cshtml`. It is not in the default mvc3- schemas, and I am not sure if it is built in to mvc4+.

Comment: @TravisJ [Http Compression has ABSOLUTELY nothing to do with Asp.Net and is completely a function of IIS](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression).  It is turned on by default unless the System Administrator is ignorant.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Or unless you are being ignorant. Server farms tend to have it disabled, which includes many hosted services. Most online sources will not allow access to IIS if it is shared hosting, nor will they enable compression so it is on the application to take care of it. Compression is done to the *response*, and can be done in ASP.NET, or do you know nothing of the HTTP Pipeline?

Comment: @TravisJ no need for name calling.  Here are some websites that use Http Compression (because it is standard for just about everyone): Ebay, Amazon, Youtube, Reddit, Gmail, Facebook, Yahoo, Wikipedia, Twitter, LinkedIn, Wordpress, Pinterest, Msn, Microsoft, Paypal, Imdb, Apple, Imgur, Ask, and I got bored, because I can't fine a website that doesn't support compresssion.  All of those websites are on server farms (pretty sure).  I'm sure they aren't all using IIS.  Compression being done in ASP.Net is totally irrelevant (who would want to rewrite something already available in IIS?).

Comment: @ErikPhilips - No need for caps, escalation, or negative insinuations but that didn't stop you. And here you still pursue a tangent to the fact that constructing extra data to send to the client is not always viable. With regards to your list, none of those sites are on a shared environment which was the reference I was making. While you can come up with a list of dozens, there are millions of shared hosted sites online who do not have access to their server. Just because you do not think it is relevant to your minutia, "don't know anyone", nor understand why it makes sense doesn't negate it.

Comment: @TravisJ I assume you weren't a Systems Administrator (being on this site, and not really being on SuperUser nor ServerFault).  As HttpCompression is 99.99% of the times out of the hand of a programmer  it's still valid, but not brought up for these types of conversation, because it's typically unknown.  As for extra data, it's off topic here because the OP never stated such a requirement.  Good for recommendations/comments, but in *my opinion* a very poor excuse to -1 a valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a manual one for that, no need to do it from a template. For example, in javascript

```
function groupAnchor(url,display){
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 a.href = url;
 a.className = "list-group-item";
 a.target = "_blank";
 a.innerHTML = display;
 return a;
}
```

And then use that function to modify your html structure

```
<div id="anchors"></div>
<script>
 document.getElementById("anchors").appendChild(groupAnchor("http://google.com","Google"));
</script>
```

Your approach to modification will more than likely be more advanced than this, but it demonstrates the concept. If you need these values to come from server side then you could always iterate over a set using `@foreach()` and issue either the whole html or script calls there -- *or*, pass the set from the server in as json and then use that in a function which is set up to manage a list of anchors.

To expand on this, it is important to avoid sending html to the view from a razor iteration. The reason being that html constructed by razor will increase the size of the page load, and if this is done in a list it can be a significant increase.

In your action, construct the list of links and then serialize them so they can be passed to the view

```
public ActionResult ViewWithLinks()
{
 var vm = new ViewModel();
 vm.Links = Json(LinkSource.ToList()).Data;
 //or for a very simple test for proof of concept
 var Numbers = Json(Enumerable.Range(0,100).ToList()).Data;
 ViewData["numbers"] = Numbers ;
 return View(vm);
}
```

where all you need is an object to hold the links in your view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
 public string text { get; set; }
 public string href { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your view you can consume this json object

```
 var allLinks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Links));
 var numbersList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["linkTest"]));//simple example
```

Now you can return to the above function in order to place it on the page by working with the array of link objects.

```
var $holder = $("<div>");
for(var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++){
 $holder.append(groupAnchor(allLinks[i].href,allLinks[i].text));
}
$("#linkArea").append($holder);
```

The benefit is that all of this javascript can be cached for your page. It is loaded once and is capable of handling large amounts of links without having to worry about sending excessive html to the client.

Comment: He must pass data to the view using the Model as he said.

Comment: @Fals - Then he should pass the data as json, as I said.

Comment: You have to return the View anyway, just do the job in the server. The View engine will process the View anyway to return to the client. Doing another http call to the server to return something that should be done in the first moment is not a good pratice. Another thread to process a JSON request? Why?

Comment: @Fals - The model can contain the json, it is just a string. All JSON does not come from AJAX. Sending information in a List should be serialized in order to avoid continuously sending erroneous data to the client.

Comment: Ok, You are right! Generating another request, grab a thread from the pool, go through almost every way in the ASP.NET pipeline just to serialize this JSON is better than return this a in the moment that the ViewEngine is creating the HTML! Makes no sense man!

Comment: @Fals - You clearly are misunderstanding. You do not have to make an ajax call to get JSON. What makes you think that, or that JSON is something other than just a string? Do you make an AJAX call for every single view model you pass in? No. So why are you stuck on thinking JSON requires an AJAX call?

Comment: The overhead for serializatiion makes sense here! And another one to make sure the string is html like. Good save me! Turning a wind into a tornado!

Comment: @Fals - Nothing compared to the overhead of waiting for the client to load an html heavy page! Iteration is representative of large sets. Doing this for a handful of items may seem like an issue, but if you were to have hundreds of links then this will save hundreds of milliseconds. Thousands will save seconds.